# Testing nested functions in jest without return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a notfications.js file which I want to write jest tests for. Can someone tell me how to approach the test cases for this.

```
import { store } from 'react-notifications-component';

/**
 * Helper function to add a notification anywhere.
 * @param {*} title string
 * @param {*} message string
 * @param {*} type  string of success, danger, info, default, warning
 */
const addNotification = (title, message, type) => {
  const options = {
    title,
    message,
    type,
    insert: 'top',
    container: 'top-right',
    animationIn: ['animated', 'fadeIn'],
    animationOut: ['animated', 'fadeOut'],
  };

  store.addNotification({
    ...options,
    dismiss: {
      duration: 5000,
      onScreen: true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
    },
  });
};

export default addNotification;
```

I read the jest documentation and read about mock functions but wasn't able to figure a lot out. First time trying to write a unit test.

> **Solution**:
>   I was able to do the testing by creating a spy for the store using jest spyOn.
>   My test was:

```
const params = {
  title: 'test',
  type: 'success',
  message: 'this is a test notification!',
};

describe('addNotification', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.spyOn(store, 'addNotification');
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  test('calls store.addNotification()', () => {
    addNotification(params.title, params.message, params.type);
    expect(store.addNotification).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

**Note**: **Please refer to the answer provided by** @slideshowp2 **it is a better** **solution.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) to mock `react-notifications-component` package. I add `{ virtual: true }` option because I didn't install this package, just for demonstration. If you had installed this package, you can remove this option.

E.g.

`notifications.js`:

```js
import { store } from 'react-notifications-component';

const addNotification = (title, message, type) => {
  const options = {
    title,
    message,
    type,
    insert: 'top',
    container: 'top-right',
    animationIn: ['animated', 'fadeIn'],
    animationOut: ['animated', 'fadeOut'],
  };

  store.addNotification({
    ...options,
    dismiss: {
      duration: 5000,
      onScreen: true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
    },
  });
};

export default addNotification;
```

`notifications.test.js`:

```js
import addNotification from './notifications';
import { store } from 'react-notifications-component';

jest.mock(
  'react-notifications-component',
  () => {
    const mStore = {
      addNotification: jest.fn(),
    };
    return { store: mStore };
  },
  { virtual: true },
);

describe('61461299', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const title = 'jest';
    const message = 'unit testing';
    const type = 'ok';
    addNotification(title, message, type);
    expect(store.addNotification).toBeCalledWith({
      title,
      message,
      type,
      insert: 'top',
      container: 'top-right',
      animationIn: ['animated', 'fadeIn'],
      animationOut: ['animated', 'fadeOut'],
      dismiss: {
        duration: 5000,
        onScreen: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
      },
    });
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61461299/notifications.test.js (11.362s)
  61461299
    ✓ should pass (4ms)

------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File              | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files         |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 notifications.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.33s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/61461299